# Is there a way to show the list of available browsers to users before opening any url in iOS

Tags: ios, openurl

I want to open an url from my application. Before opening it in browser , i need to show the list of browsers available and let the user select the browser. Is it possible on a non jailbroken device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible in current sdk

But you can try this way

It does not handle list of used URL schemes

However, one can catch only these web browsers installed

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Google_Chrome